# Unwind segue isn't editing a selected cell but keeps appending to the array

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data, unwind-segue

So I'm simply working on a contacts page and want to be able to select the cell and edit the data. The contacts information appears in the contact page, so the particular contact is being sent. It's just when I hit save it creates a new contact instead of modifying the selected one.

```
@IBAction func unwindToContacts(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? NewContactViewController, contact = sourceViewController.contact {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update an existing contact.
            contacts[selectedIndexPath.row] = contact
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        } else {
            // Add a new contact.
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: contacts.count, inSection: 0)
            contacts.append(contact)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
        }
        // Save the contacts.
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Error: \(error)" + "Description: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Solved it by simply keeping track of the NSIndexPath and passing it to and from.

Comment: I don't think you can count on tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow to work when segueing back from another ViewController.

Comment: I thought so too, but in this example from a Core Data book it seems it can. An example from the book only uses an unwind and a prepareforsegue for navigation.

Comment: I believe there's an option for clearing selection on presentation, that may be something you need to look at